# What was the name of Delhi during the period of Akbar ruling in parts of India?

Tags: india, 16th-century, cities

Jallaudin Akbar ruled some parts of India. During his empire he had Delhi (Modern day state) as his capital, but it was known by some other name.

What was the name that was used for the capital during the time that Akbar ruled?

Comment: Are you asking because you know the answer or because you don't? Many of your questions sound like quiz questions. Also, please add links to Wikipedia pages of Akbar etc. for those who are unfamiliar with this Indian king.

Comment: I know the answer when I was small but I forgot now and couldn't recall though. That's not my problem if my questions sounds like a quiz for you. My aim here is to share and gain knowledge and not to do something else. Yeah, here is the link for this unfamiliar king (as u mentioned) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akbar

Comment: coleopterist --I don't think we should ask people to add wiki links to their questions unless of course they are questioning material on the wiki itself. Though I am happy to have a community discussion for this on the meta. @Balaji he is right on one count though --the question definitely can be improved. Sadly I have no edit privileges.

Comment: Akbar did not rule some part of India but a large swathes of the Indian subcontinent.

Comment: @MonsterTruck I'm not saying that people **should** do anything. It's usually helpful though. While Akbar might have been a famous king in India, I dare say that he is not all that well known outside the country. In any event, looking up the Wikipedia pages of both Akbar and Delhi would have answered this consequentially off-topic question.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Delhi#Early_history shows that the city was called Delhi (or Dilli) *at least* since the 12/13th century.

Therefore, when Akbar assumed throne in 1556, the city would have been called Delhi.

There are however more concrete sources than this simple extrapolation. Humayun Nama refers to the city as Delhi. You can read it [here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/mealac/pritchett/00litlinks/gulbadan/part05.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure but I remember the media (in India) addressing Delhi as "HASTHINA".
Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: No, I got the answer but I have to verify it.

Answer (score -2):

hmmm....i think "**indraprasta**" was the older name of delhi. But am not clear whether the name changed or not, during the period of akbar.

Comment: Indraprashta was not Delhi but close to Delhi in current day state of Haryana.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. @PravinCG